# Python histogram bins issue - the bins don't match my array

Tags: python, histogram

So I'm trying to make a simple histogram of a simple question.
I have an array of weights that fall into 17 categories, so I'm thinking of using 17 bins.

I'd like one each array to have their own bin but I'm struggling to set it up correctly.

I set up the axis with 700, 1091 as this is the lowest and highest weight (excluded) and then 0,2 as I know the max number of occurences in an array is 2.

But my histogram looks like this :
[image: Histogram]
It's wrong as I know there should only be 3 bars going up to 2, and the rest staying at 1.
Does that makes sense?

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
     
# dataset
weights = np.array([901, 870, 970, 790, 1090, 960, 980, 820, 840, 890, 
                    1010, 920, 700, 880, 910, 890, 790, 810, 990, 750])

# histogram
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize =(10, 7))
ax.hist(weights, bins = 17)
plt.axis([700,1091,0,2])
    
# Show plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: I dont think its intuitive to get a histogram to work the way you want it to. Histograms are usually used to plot a frequency distribution of numerical values. It sounds more to me like you want the categorical funtionality of a barchart?

Comment: Yes I think you're right. I'm trying to make the x axis inegal by doing that, which doesn't work!
Thanks!

Comment: Please post what the expected output is - the one from which you intend to plot the frequency distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can define the bin size in the histogram, but not its specific end points.  You could probably get what you're wanting with 30 bins (10 units each), but even then it gets confusing to set the inclusive/exclusive ends.

Agree with Bjarke Kingo, a bar chart is likely more of what you're looking for.